# Quality of Show with two Graphics3D: intersection quality

Tags: graphics3d

I plot following two shapes with Graphics 3D:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Yellow, Ellipsoid[{1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/10), 1/E^(1/10)}, {1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/10), 1/E^(1/10)}]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}], Graphics3D[{Black, Sphere[{1/E^(2/5), 1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/5)}, 1]}]]
```

with the output

[image]

As one can see the quality of the intersection is very bad. How can I make it more smooth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> {HorizontalPoints, VerticalPoints}}`

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
   Ellipsoid[{1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/10), 1/E^(1/10)}, {1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/10), 
     1/E^(1/10)}]},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> {100, 100}}],
 Graphics3D[{Black, Sphere[{1/E^(2/5), 1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/5)}, 1]},
  Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> {100, 100}}]]
```

[image]

However, note that you can use a single [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
  Ellipsoid[{1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/10), 1/E^(1/10)}, {1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/10), 
    1/E^(1/10)}],
  Black, Sphere[{1/E^(2/5), 1/E^(1/5), 1/E^(1/5)}, 1]},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> {100, 100}}]
```

[image]